# Prove that, if 2 angles of a spherical triangle are equal, then the triangle is an isosceles spherical triangle

Tags: triangles, spherical-trigonometry

So the question goes:
"An Isosceles Spherical Triangle is a triangle that has 2 sides of equal length. Prove that, if 2 angles of a spherical triangle are equal, then the triangle is an isosceles spherical triangle."

I've only started learning spherical trigonometry a few days ago so I am still very new to all of this. I've learnt the cosine and sine theorems, but not sure how to use them to prove this. I'd love for some help and ideally if you do decide to respond to this, please try to keep it simple as my knowledge is quite limited.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What axioms and theorems are you allowed to use? I'd argue it from symmetry but I'm not sure that would be acceptable.

Comment: Ive learnt the cos and sine theorems, A=Er^2 and spherical excess but those last 2 aren't very helpful. What Ive done is used the cos rule for cosB and cos C (as angles B and C are = in my triangle ABC). As I know they are equal, I made the equations equal and worked from there. -cosC*cosA + sinC*sinA*cosb = -cosB*cosA + sinB*sinA*cosc. As a triangle can have from 180 to 540 degrees, B and C thus must be less than 540 degrees total, so one angle must be between 90 and 270 degrees. But in this case there could be multiple solutions for cos so im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A=B=X$ (look [hier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) for definitions), then we need to show that $a=b$. Using the sine rule, we have $$\sin(A) / \sin(a) =\sin(X) / \sin(a) = \sin(X)/\sin(b)=\sin(B) / \sin(b)$$ or $$Y =\color{red}{\sin(a) = \sin(b)}$$ We also could use the cosine rules $$\cos(a) = \cos(b)\cos(c)+\sin(b)\sin(c)\cos(A)$$ $$\cos(b) = \cos(c)\cos(a)+\sin(a)\sin(c)\cos(B)$$ or $$\cos(a) = \cos(b)\cos(c)+Y\sin(c)\cos(X)$$ $$\cos(b) = \cos(a)\cos(c)+Y\sin(c)\cos(X),$$ because $X=A=B$ and $Y=\sin(a) = \sin(b)$.

Subtracting *correctly* gives $(\cos(a)-\cos(b))(1+\cos(c))=0$. This leads to $\color{red}{\cos(a) = \cos(b)}$ ***or*** $\cos(c)=-1$.

If $\color{red}{\cos(a) = \cos(b)}$, then with $\color{red}{\sin(a) = \sin(b)}$ we are done and $a=b$.

Otherwise if $\cos(a)\neq\cos(b) $ and $\color{red}{\cos(c)=-1}$, then with $\color{red}{\sin(a) = \sin(b)}$...

Comment: There exist two great circle arcs of lengths $x$ and $y$ such that $x\neq y$ but $\sin(x)=\sin(y).$ So I think we may need something more than $\sin(a)=\sin(b)$ to conclude that $a=b.$

Comment: You're right, maybe the cosine rules will do the trick

Comment: Yes, prove the cosines also are equal and together with the equal sines this proves the angles are equal.

Comment: What Ive done is used the cos rule for cosB and cos C (as angles B and C are = in my triangle ABC). As I know they are equal, I made the equations equal and worked from there. -cosC*cosA + sinC*sinA*cosb = -cosB*cosA + sinB*sinA*cosc. As a triangle can have from 180 to 540 degrees, B and C thus must be less than 540 degrees total, so one angle must be between 90 and 270 degrees. But in this case there could be multiple solutions for cos so im not sure what to do. If I'm wrong here please correct me as I'm not so sure.

Comment: Actually, subtracting gives $(\cos a - \cos b)(1 + \cos c) = 0$ so *either* $\cos a = \cos b$ *or* $\cos c = -1$. That still leaves to rule out the case that $a \neq b, \sin a = \sin b, \cos c = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem in trigonometry; rather the proof is the same in spherical geometry as it is in Euclidean:

Let the two angles be at $A$ and $B$, the third vertex being called $C$. Now draw a segment from $C$ to the midpoint $M$ of $\overline{AB}$. Then you have two triangles $\triangle CMA$ and $\triangle CMB$, congruent by SAS.